How to create date wise traces.svclog file while using WCF
I have a WCF service that creates traces.svclog file and tracks all the information but,
I have a scenario where I have to create new traces.svclog file everyday, so the older svclog files can be archived and it doesnot consume much space on server.
Any help is highly appreciated.
tried multple solutions, did not worked.

WCF tracing was designed to be a troubleshooting method, so relying on it daily or more is on the wrong track.

Add content to the server's web.config file or the client's app.config file:
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="C:\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>

The file storage location can be modified:
<add initializeData="C:\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" 
This is MSDN document.
Update:
It's easy to add time to a file. The name of the file is added to the code. You can simply add the time to your name.
Such as:
<add initializeData="C:\\TracingAndLogging-service 2024-6-13.svclog"
     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml" />

But I'll tell you that because the configuration file is read once, you'll need to re-date the run service every time you want to generate a file.
Of course, this file contains all your actions and dates.


Can we have a current date appended in file name ?

The file name can be customized. You can add a date.

I have never worked with traces file, can you provide the code snippet to achieve the same.

Currently, most log generation is profile-based. And you can see the corresponding operation time in the log. All you need to do is put my config code above into web.config.

Actually, I want to append the date in the filename of the traces file, can this be achieved?
